# How do I "justify" a text when a `th`'s text starts pushing the table?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How do I justify a `th`'s text when its text starts pushing the table making it get bigger that its original size

I'd like to make the table "break a line" (AKA justify) when it can't squeeze the other cell anymore.

**Original:**

[image: original]

**What is happening now (The problem):**
[image: problem]

**How it should be:**(instead of increasing width, it increases height, and keep the whole text)
[image: should be]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My_Littlest_Table_Shop</title>
  <style>
    table{
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
    }

    table, th, td{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="header" align="center">idkajsdhfkjhaksdfhkjashfkjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaksdfjjjjjj</th>
      <th class="header" align="center">id</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="header" align="center">id</td>
       <td class="header" align="center">id</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>----------------200px--------------></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These guys should do the trick:

```
table { 
  table-layout: fixed;
}
th, td {
  /* not sure if you want this    
  width: 100px; */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My_Littlest_Table_Shop</title>
  <style>
    table{
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
    }

    table, th, td{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    table { 
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    th, td {
      /* not sure if you want this    
      width: 100px; */
  
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="header" align="center">idkajsdhfkjhaksdfhkjashfkjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaksdfjjjjjj</th>
      <th class="header" align="center">id</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="header" align="center">id</td>
       <td class="header" align="center">id</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>----------------200px--------------></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, it's amazing, I'm gonna try it right now +1

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to alter the css to allow word break and justify the text

```
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLLkvt4m/

Just add the CSS mentioned below:

```
td, th {
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```